# Screen Never Sleeps (And Turns On Automatically)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, nvidia

My xset settings keep getting reset. This is causing my monitor to never sleep. Even when I try to force my monitor to sleep using the command `xset dpms force off`the monitor almost immediately turns back on.

I have tried unplugging my mouse to make sure that it isn't causing a mouse event to trigger the display. I also do not have a wireless card, so I know it cannot be a wifi event as discussed in this thread:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1317747

I don't have gnome-screensaver installed (its discussed as a possible culprit in the thread above.

The output of my `xset -q` command is below. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  33
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x48    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

I know this says that my display should never enter standby, suspend, or turn off. However, this is because these values keep getting set back to 0.

I'm wondering if it could be something with my nvidia drivers? Here is the output of nvidia-smi:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.56       Driver Version: 418.56       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P4000        Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 48%   46C    P0    29W / 105W |    632MiB /  8117MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1469      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            77MiB |
|    0      1515      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                           6MiB |
|    0     21106      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           269MiB |
|    0     21198      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         225MiB |
|    0     21617      G   ...quest-channel-token=7833489270476747312    49MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Let me know if there is any other information that might be helpful. If someone can help me solve this I'd be very grateful!

Comment: If you are using a program like redshift it might be resetting your monitor frequently.

Comment: I have "Night Light" enabled -- but I just disabled that and it didn't seem to help.

Comment: To verify it worked, what does this return? `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled`

Comment: it returned false